# What is the purpose of this conditional markup?

Tags: visualforce, conditional

I am trying to sort records and I encountered the below markup in a Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Phone{!IF(sortExpression=='Phone',IF(sortDirection='ASC','?','?'),'')}">
    <apex:param value="Phone" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" > 
    </apex:param>
</apex:commandLink>
```

Here I know the use of `<apex:param>`, but I do not understand the `IF` function. Why is it being used in this way?

Comment: Visualforce isn't code, it's markup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code was actually copy-pasted from a UTF-8 file to an ASCII file at some point, which turned the original symbols into "?", because they were not convertable from UTF-8. The original code probably should have looked like this:

```
Phone{!IF(sortExpression=='Phone',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▲','▼'),'')
```

This is a pretty common design; if the field is sorted by "sortExpression", then display either arrow, depending on if sortDirection is ascending or not.

The apex:param on the next line is used by the apex:commandLink's `ViewData` method to set the sortExpression field to Phone when the command link is clicked, thus causing the sorting to change.

**Edit:** In fact, it may have literally been ripped from one of my [older answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/161180) that demonstrates how to do this properly.

Answer (score 5):

This code is very confused. Let's pull out the `IF` expression:

```
{!IF(sortExpression=='Phone', 
     IF(sortDirection='ASC',
        '?',
        '?'),
    '')}
```

This `IF` results in one of two values. If `sortExpression` is `'Phone'`, the whole `IF` evaluates to `'?'`. The inner `IF()` function effectively does nothing, returning `"?"` regardless of whether it is true or false. It could be replaced with the constant string `'?`'

If `sortExpression` is not `'Phone'`, the whole thing evaluates to an empty string, `''`.

Edit: unfortunately I cannot delete this answer as it's already been accepted; please refer to sfdcfox's answer, which divined what was behind this code.

Comment: the code was very confusing that is why i didn't get much from it

Comment: This answer, unfortunately, is incorrect.

Comment: I'm glad you caught the actual intent behind the code, which was not apparent to me, but I'd say it's the code that is wrong here!

Comment: @DavidReed It's still incorrect, as apex:param doesn't do what you think it does. Try looking at the answer I linked in my answer for an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Oy. You're quite right, of course, I misinterpreted that.