# List sorting by custom field

Tags: apex, case, list

I dont know how to sort a list of SObject Case.

I have a `List<Case> newCases` which i iterate over in for cycle, where i save Cases to my new `List<Case> casesList`.

```
for (Case newCase : newCases) {
            if(newCase.Case_Content__c == '111' && newCase.Status == '24'){
                String cuid = newCase.CUID__c;
                cuidSet.add(cuid);
                casesList.add(newCase);
                casesList.sort(); //TODO sorting by CUID__c
            }
        }
```

What i need to do is, to sort this new list by field CUID__c. So the Cases with same CUID are together.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Strongly related, possibly duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/161180

Answer (score 16):

You have to implement a Wrapper class with comparable interface for this to happen.

> To implement a custom sort order for sObjects in lists, create a
>   wrapper class for the sObject and implement the Comparable interface.
>   The wrapper class contains the sObject in question and implements the
>   compareTo method, in which you specify the sort logic.

Eg:

```
global class OpportunityWrapper implements Comparable {

    public Opportunity oppy;

    // Constructor
    public OpportunityWrapper(Opportunity op) {
        oppy = op;
    }

    // Compare opportunities based on the opportunity amount.
    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        // Cast argument to OpportunityWrapper
        OpportunityWrapper compareToOppy = (OpportunityWrapper)compareTo;

        // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (oppy.Amount > compareToOppy.oppy.Amount) {
            // Set return value to a positive value.
            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (oppy.Amount < compareToOppy.oppy.Amount) {
            // Set return value to a negative value.
            returnValue = -1;
        }

        return returnValue;       
    }
}
```

And then to Sort just call Sort Method after adding records to your wrapper list

```
        OpportunityWrapper[] oppyList = new List<OpportunityWrapper>();
        Date closeDate = Date.today().addDays(10);
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='Edge Installation',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Prospecting',
            Amount=50000)));
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='United Oil Installations',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Needs Analysis',
            Amount=100000)));
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='Grand Hotels SLA',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Prospecting',
            Amount=25000)));

        // Sort the wrapper objects using the implementation of the 
        // compareTo method.
        oppyList.sort();
```

So in your case, the CaseWrapper will compare `CUID__c` to determine sorting order in the compareTo method.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can query the Cases again Where Ids IN: casesList, then Order BY CUID__c ASC/DESC.
Yeah this is funny but it works.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 things have improved. Salesforce introduced the [Comparator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm#CustomSortSection) interface, something that Java had at least since version 1.2. No need for wrappers or another query. In order to sort according to a field CUID__c of the Case object, you'd implement a class like this:

```apex
public class CaseCUIDComparator implements Comparator<Case> {
    public Integer compare(Case case0, Case case1) {
        if(case0.CUID__c == null) return 1;
        if(case1.CUID__c == null) return -1;
        return case0.CUID__c < case1.CUID__c ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

The unit test demonstrates its use and its impact:

```apex
@IsTest
private static void verifyComparator() {
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{
        new Case(CUID__c = 'B'),
        new Case(CUID__c = null),
        new Case(CUID__c = 'A'),
        new Case(CUID__c = 'D'),
        new Case(CUID__c = 'A'),
        new Case(CUID__c = 'C')
    };

    Test.startTest();
    cases.sort(new CaseCUIDComparator());
    Test.stopTest();

    Assert.areEqual('A', cases[0].CUID__c);
    Assert.areEqual('A', cases[1].CUID__c);
    Assert.areEqual('B', cases[2].CUID__c);
    Assert.areEqual('C', cases[3].CUID__c);
    Assert.areEqual('D', cases[4].CUID__c);
    Assert.areEqual(null, cases[5].CUID__c);
}
```